# How can I avoid duplicate random three-word combinations from a table of words?

Tags: php, random, combinations

I am trying to pull a list of words from the database, create a unique three-word combination in the form $word1.$word2.$word3, and assign it to a star.

I want to avoid duplicate combinations - I want each star to have a unique three-word identifier.

My current method involves creating an array of all possible three-word combinations and then deleting each combination from the array once it has been assigned to a star. I intend, however, to use a few-thousand words in my word list, which means this array will contain tens of billions of combinations, so this method seems incredibly inefficient.

How can I achieve this more effectively? My initial thoughts are that I should loop through each star, create and assign a three-word combination, then add the combo to an array, and for each star, check if the newly generated combo is in the array.

**Code**

```
 <?php

    // Initiate connection to the database...
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'stellar');

    // Query database of words
    $words_sql = "SELECT * FROM words";
    $words_res = mysqli_query($db, $words_sql)or die(mysqli_error());

    // Create array of words
    $words = array();

    // Loop through each word from the database and add each to an array 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($words_res)){
         $words[] = $row['word'];
    }

    // Create array of all possible three-word combinations, from which we will randomly select our combinations 
    $triplets = array();
    foreach ($words as $word1){
        foreach ($words as $word2){
            foreach($words as $word3){
                if ($word1 !== $word2 && $word2 !== $word3 && $word1 !== $word3){
                     $triplets[] = "$word1.$word2.$word3";
                }
            }    
        }
    }

    // Pull all stars from database
    $stars_sql = "SELECT * FROM stars";
    $stars_res = mysqli_query($db, $stars_sql)or die(mysqli_error());

    // Loop through every star in the array
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stars_res)){
         // Store the star name and star_id in variables
         $star    = $row['star_name'];
         $star_id = $row['star_id'];

         // Set $three_words as a random combination from the array of possible combinations...
         $ran_num     = array_rand($triplets);
         $three_words = $triplets[$ran_num];

         // ...and remove this particular combination, in order to prevent repating combinations
         array_splice($triplets, $ran_num, 1);

         // Attach the random 3-word combination to the star 
         echo $star.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$three_words.'<br/><br/>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: If you have 1000 words you would have 1000000000 possible combinations, how does this compare to the total stars you need to name, e.g., is it like 100 stars or more like 500000000 stars?

Comment: I'd like to start with ~2.5 million stars, so I guess I only require ~300 words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is (possibly) a minor tweak you can make to get MySQL to do some of the heavy lifting for you.

```
$words_sql = "SELECT CONCAT(w1.word,'.',w2.word,'.',w3.word) as triplet 
FROM (words w1 JOIN words w2 ON w1.word != w2.word) 
    JOIN words w3 ON w3.word != w1.word AND w3.word != w2.word";
$words_res = mysqli_query($db, $words_sql)or die(mysqli_error());

// Create array of words
$words = array();

// Loop through each word from the database and add each to an array 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($words_res)){
     $triplets[] = $row['triplet'];
}
```

This is probably as good as you're going to get because by the end of the process you'll have assigned all triplets to a star, which means whether you pre-generate the triplets or generate them later, you'll end up generating them all anyway.

Now there is an alternative solution for the case where the number of triplets are much much greater than the number of stars you need to name: say you have 2.5 million stars but 2000 words (or 8 billion triplets). In this case the stars are a tiny fraction of your possible triplets so you can do the following:

```
$words = array();

// Loop through each word from the database and add each to an array 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($words_res)){
     $words[] = $row['word'];
}

// Pull all stars from database
$stars_sql = "SELECT * FROM stars";
$stars_res = mysqli_query($db, $stars_sql)or die(mysqli_error());

// Loop through every star in the array
$used = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stars_res)){
     // Store the star name and star_id in variables
     $star    = $row['star_name'];
     $star_id = $row['star_id'];

     do {
         //Generate non-repeating triplet of words (sample without replacement?)
         $word1 = array_rand($words);
         do {
           $word2 = array_rand($words);
         } while ($word2 == $word1);  

         do {
           $word3 = array_rand($words);
         } while ($word3 == $word2 || $word1 == $word3);  

         $triplet = $words[$word1].".".$words[$word2].".".$words[$word3];
     } while (isset($used[$triplet])); //Try again if we've already used it. Very unlikely.

     $used[$triplet] = true; //Keep track of what we've used.   
     echo $star.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$triplet.'<br/><br/>';      
 }
```

In the second case, this works because the chance we generate the same triplet twice is very small because of the possible number of triplets and the fact that we're using only a tiny fraction of them in total.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 

What seems to be happening is that when the script creates a triplet that has already been generated, it falls into an infinite loop of creating $word1, $word2 and $word3 over and over again for the same star. 

I'm going to have a play with it to see if I can fix it. I'm using 10,000 stars and 2,272 words. It seems the array_rand() function isn't very random. I'd appreciate any thoughts you have.

Comment: Ok, fixed it. I used the random_int($min, $max) function instead, setting $max = count($words), and $min = $max - $max. The script now generates and prints 10,000 unique combinations in ~2 seconds. 

Thanks very much for your help.